# Why don't we allow low reputation users to insert more than two images in their posts?

Tags: discussion, new-users, privileges, question-restrictions

I was searching for privileges one can get after a certain amount of reputation, and I ended up with this question in my mind: Why don't we allow users with low reputation to insert more than two images or links in their posts?

Is it good to make restrictions for them? Let's say someone is going to post a good question and he/she needs to insert three images to explain it properly; because this can't be done the question may become vague or incomplete to answer, and ultimately be flagged by others. Is this a rational decision for those users?

Yes, I believe that restrictions should be there to make a control over new users like for voting privileges but is it good to make restrictions on Questions and Answers?

Here is my question:

**Is it decent to restrict new users in such a manner?**

Comment: What circumstances can you think of that require *one* picture, let alone *two*, unless it's to describe a pseudo-abstract problem?

Comment: So you think....This is good to make restrictions to quality posts

Comment: You can always link to the image, then gain enough rep and edit it to make the images display. Same for links (can be disabled with backticks).

Comment: Use vertical panorama :D

Comment: But what if the question get flagged before you could gain the enough rep ...?

Comment: @Ðeepak: The point is that your post alone should have enough content to not warrant a deletion in the first place. The links/images should not be the main contributing factor to the content of the answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In my opinion, links and images should be a relatively rare thing in both questions and answers. One important thing to note about both of them is that they don't contribute to searchability of content. In *many* cases, it's much better to simply describe things better, include relevant code, and the like. Quite often, links/images *might* indicate a mild tendency of a post toward being localized.

That said, they are sometimes very useful, anyway. But making good use of them can be a little bit of an art. On an average, higher-reputation users will *tend* to be better at this art than new users.

In my opinion, we tend to get better content when we encourage people to describe their question/answer with text, directly entered here. A tiny red light goes off in my head whenever I see links or images in a post. To me, (not as a moderator, but merely as a reader), a link/image has the burden of proving it was needed in the first place.

Links can also be used for spamming, of course, and there is a significant reverse correlation between reputation and propensity to spam (with a number of prolific exceptions which help prove the rule). But to be honest, I don't think that the *number* of spammy links in a post is as big a deal as the mere existence of a *spammy post* in the first place.

---

Please note it's important to parse the wording I've used here carefully. I'm not speaking in absolutes, but in terms of tendencies and relative desirability.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, perhaps, images should be relatively rare, but on places like [android.se] they can be crucial in sussing out the actual problem. That said, I don't think new users should be able to post an unlimited number of images.

Comment: @aleverett Good point! I imagine Graphic Design might be another!